# How to use levenshtein function in Sequelize ORM?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to perform a search query in PostgreSQL database using Sequelize orm.

The Levenshtein distance (a.k.a edit distance) is a measure of similarity between two strings. It is defined as the minimum number of changes required to convert string a into string b (this is done by inserting, deleting or replacing a character in string a). The smaller the Levenshtein distance, the more similar the strings are.

Comment: Looks like Postgres already has this kind of stuff: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html - you may need to write a raw query, though, but I'm sure Sequelize's "like" option should work...

Comment: I am trying to perform a search operation where martinluther should match martin luther.